# Best way to modify objects in list using values from another list

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have an entity `Issue` as following :

```
public class Issue{
    private IssueElementEnum issueElement;
    private IssueTypeEnum issueType;
    private String title;
}
```

And I have a list of `Issue` which I get from DAO:

```
List<Issue> issues = issueDAO.findAll();
```

In this list I have some `Issue` object where `issue.getIssueElement() == IssueElementEnum.USER`, I want to update these object by changing there `title` field, for that I have to filter the list of `issues` and create a list of type String from the result list, then I have to pass this list to a service that will return a list of new titles which will be used to replace the old titles.

This is what I tried :

```
List<Issue> issues = issueDAO.findAll();
List<Issue> userIssues = issues.stream().filter(a -> a.getIssueElement() == IssueElementEnum.USER).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> oldTitles = userIssues.stream().map(a -> a.getTitle()).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<User> users = userSVC.findByTitles(oldTitles);
for (User user : users) {
    for (Issue issue : issues) {
        if (user.getKey().equals(issue.getTitle())) {
            issue.setTitle(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to write this ?

Comment: *Is there any other way to write this?* Well, of course there is. What is *the best* (TM) depends on your problem: Quickest runtime, lowest memory consumption, for 10 or 100000 elements? Async or sync consumption of the result? Including or excluding preceding and following database operation? Etc. IMHO a highly subjective question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to follow exactly what's going on here, but there are 2 improvements I can spot.

Firstly, there is no point in `userIssues` at all (although it seems odd that in the last step you iterate over all `issues` rather than `userIssues`. Is this right?). Just do

```
List<String> oldTitles = issues
                            .stream()
                            .filter(a -> a.getIssueElement() == IssueElementEnum.USER)
                            .map(Issue::getTitle)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Secondly, the nested loops appear unnecessary. I'm not 100% clear on your logic but something like this ought to work.

```
Map<String, User> usersByKey = new HashMap<>();
for (User user : users)
    usersByKey.put(user.getKey(), user);
for (Issue issue : issues) {
    User user = usersByKey.get(issue.getTitle());
    if (user != null) 
        issue.setTitle(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
}
```